# Bind the query to the Gridview in asp.net using SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have two queries which are specified below.

```
select (t1.projectID),t2.FID,t1.Title,t1.ConsultancyAgency,t1.Client 
from (select * from consultancy_det ) t1 
inner join (select * from contribution_fid_map) t2 on t1.ProjectID = t2.ProjectID
```

Second Query is:

```
select name,fid from Personal_det;ss
```

Output of First Query

```
ProjectID      FID               Title                                         ConsulancyAgency    Client
   1         mahe001508     Android Application Development Project Ideas       MAHE               ICAS
   1         7894           Android Application Development Project Ideas       MAHE               ICAS
   2         2222                     abc                                       MIT                KMC
   2         7894                     abc                                       MIT                KMC
```

Output of second query:

```
  Name        FID   
 abcgh        2222
 ANaa         7894
 hhk          faw1
Shreyas Tg  mahe001508
NewFaculty  mcis001
```

Now using those above query i need to bind the data to the **Gridview** in asp.net and the **gridview** should be seen some what like this.

```
ProjectID     FID              Title                                         ConsulancyAgency  Client
   1         Shreyas Tg     Android Application Development Project Ideas      MAHE             ICAS
             ANaa                                                                        
   2         abcgh              abc                                            KMC               MIT                
             ANaa
```

Is this possible to display the data like this in gridview?? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want the FID and Name columns from **Both** subqueries to be bound to the `GridView`?

First you'll need to alias the columns:

```
select
    q1_FID = q1.FID,
    q1_Name = q1.Name,
    q2_FID = q2.FID,
    q2_Name = q2.Name,
    other_columns
from
(
   select fid, name, projectID from yourTable
) as q1
inner join
  yourOtherTable q2 on q2.projectID = q1.projectID
```

Then you just name the columns aliases in your Column set up for the `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="yourGV" runat="server">
    <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="q1_FID" HeaderText="First FID"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="q1_Name" HeaderText="First Name"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="q2_FID" HeaderText="Second FID"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="q2_Name" HeaderText="Second Name"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**EDIT**

Updated SQL query:

```
select
name, t1_fid, q.projectID, pd.fid, title, consultancyAgency, client
from
personal_det pd 
inner join
(
select (t1.projectID),t2.FID,t1.Title,t1.ConsultancyAgency,t1.Client 
from (select * from consultancy_det ) t1 
inner join (select * from contribution_fid_map) t2 on t1.ProjectID = t2.ProjectID
) as q on q.fid = pd.fid
```

Comment: Actually i need Name instead of FID in the ouput where in FID is FK constraint for two tables `Contribution_FID_Map` and `personal_det` but Name is not present in `Contribution_FID_Map`